# Putting template in template cache before rendering angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-templatecache

I have created a directive to put element html code in template cache-

```
.directive('putInCache', function ($templateCache) {
    return {
       link: function (scope, element) {
           $templateCache.put('name', element.html());
       }
    };
})
```

I am using it in html like this-

```
<div put-in-cache class="modal">
     <div class="modal-body">
         <div ng-repeat="result in results">
             {{ result }}
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that element.html() return ng-repeat code as `<-- ng-repeat result in results -->` due to which ng-repeat does not work in modal template.

Any ideas how can I put the actual html before ng-repeat rendering in cache

PS - I can't use script ng-template or define template in js, hence created this directive.

Comment: try wrapping it with `setTimeout`

Comment: Why you cant use ng-template? What are you trying to do is to write your own ng-template...

Comment: because I want the same code to be present in my markup, without being wrapped in script tags